# Is there a way to reset the Administrator on mac

Tags: mac, administrator

I forgot the Admin password, and is there a way that i can reset it without using third party apps and things?

Comment: I think you need to say which Mac.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.